# select car of list, insert value to cookies- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have list of cars models, and i trying to insert the value of select to the cookie with jQuery.

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var singleValues = $("#car").val(); //I NEED TO BE INSIDE
    $('#continue').click(function() {
        $.cookie("car", singleValues);
    })

    $('#continue').click(function() {
        var singleValues = $("#car").val();
        $.cookie("car", singleValues);
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id='car'>
    <option value="mazda">mazda</option>
    <option value="honda">honda</option>
</select>
<a href='/' id='continue'>#<div id='continue_button'></div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

but the cookie didnt make.... why?

thank you very much about your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in a document ready handler. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        $('#continue').click(function() {
            var singleValues = $("#car").val();
            $.cookie("car", singleValues);
        })
    });
</script>
```

Currently your code is attaching the events before the elements exist in the DOM.